# Не могу добавить папку в проект NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Пишет что "папка пакета уже используется в проекте"

Чистил руками папку проектов IDE, переустанавливал NetBeans, переносил папку в другую директорию на жестком диске. 
Куда копнуть еще?

Comment: Посмотрите другие свои прожекты в каком из них используется эта папка. Если что можете попробовать удалить кеш нетбинса C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\

Comment: Блин,тот же результат.

Comment: Просмотрите файлы в дирректории `nbproject` вашего проекта на наличие вашего каталога. Собираете проект с помощью `ant`? `maven`? Проверьте `pom.xml` файл, если `maven`. На крайний случай создайте новый проект и перетащите туда свои исходники

Answer (score 2):

У меня была такая трабла, решилась банально - просто закрыл Netbeans, удалил все из старой директории, запустил Netbeans и открыл проект в новой. Все проблема решилась.